# How to define working voltage class net to calculte the creepage?

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, high-voltage, pcb-layers, creepage

I work of a project of single phase PFC converter and I need to define the working voltage to each each NET of Schematic to calculate creepage distance.

I have a question about the low voltage of NET including the driver of MOSFET( +15V) the sensing (+3.3V ) and also the low voltage of control board; it will be some class of high voltage of PFC (+380V)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to define working voltage class net to calculate the creepage?

First you will need to get a copy of the standard that you want to design your product to. (Like IEC61010-1) This will depend on what kind of product it is and what market you are going to sell it in, I don't know which part of the IEC standards pertain to industrial products.

Then you will look at the table and determine the pollution degree:

> Pollution Degrees and Overvoltages Pollution degree is divided into
>   four categories. The following definitions are based on those in IEC
>   60664.3
>
> • Pollution degree 1. No pollution or only dry, nonconductive
>   pollution occurs. The pollution has no influence (example: sealed or
>   potted products).
>
> • Pollution degree 2. Normally only nonconductive pollution occurs.
>   Occasionally a temporary conductivity caused by condensation must be
>   expected (example: product used in typical office environment).
>
> • Pollution degree 3. Conductive pollution occurs, or dry, nonconductive
>   pollution occurs that becomes conductive due to expected condensation
>   (example: products used in heavy industrial environments that are
>   typically exposed to pollution such as dust).
>
> • Pollution degree 4. Pollution generates persistent conductivity
>   caused, for instance, by conductive dust or by rain or snow.

Your standard will have a table like this:
[image]
[Source for table and quote](http://www.frontdoor.biz/HowToPCB/HowToPCB-extra/CreepageandClearance.pdf)

You then have to keep every trace on a PCB X ammount of distance away from every other trace. So if its 480Vrms, and pollution deg 2 you need 2mm of clearance.

This is just an example, you need to find the spec that pertains to you. Get a regulatory consultant if necessary and\or buy the relevant standards (they aren't cheap)

Comment: Thank you : the creepage is  defined  as the distance along  insulator between two conductor , and the clearance is distance measured am AIR between two conductor .  So for example So if its 480Vrms, and pollution deg 2 you need 2mm of clearance ; and For +15Vrms ;pollution deg 2 you ->0.6mm of clearance ; th question  is what distance  between 480rms and 15Vrms ? Best regards

Comment: In that example, You still need 2mm of clearance, this even means pins on relays and isolators

Comment: this rule applied also for current and voltage sensing ?  because there will be in the same region of voltage

Comment: Only the voltage level is considered from trace to trace

Comment: the voltage level  of sensing  is low  but  near of high voltage we consider the clearance of 2mm also?

Comment: The highest voltage is considered between two traces (and the highest possible voltage on the trace)